# Couting occurrences of each value in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to sort and splice an array, however I'm finding it very confusing.

I have pulled my data from a mysql table:

```
$total = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders");
```

I am  then sorting each column into an array:

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($total))
{
 $cst[] = $result['customer'];
 $partnumber[] = $result['partnumber'];
 $misc[] = $result['misc'];
}
```

now, misc has many entries that repeat in a random order e.g.

```
$misc = array(
              [0] => red, 
              [1] = >red, 
              [2] => blue, 
              [3] => blue, 
              [4] => blue,
              [5] => green,
              [6] =>red
              )
```

QUESTION: What is the best way of counting the number of each red, blue or green elements in $misc? How could I create an array such that `$misc_num['red'] = 3` etc.?

Comment: Have you thought of sorting and counting the values within your SQL query?

Comment: I have, I was trying to limit the number of server requests to I could do one call then filter using PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($total))
{
 $cst[] = $result['customer'];
 $partnumber[] = $result['partnumber'];
 $misc[] = $result['misc'];

 if(array_key_exists($result['misc'], $misc_num)) {
   $misc_num[$result['misc']] += 1;
 } else {
   $misc_num[$result['misc']] = 1;
 }
}
```

I think that should do it!

Comment: +1 for avoiding two loops. Could be a bit simplified: `if(!array_key_exists($result['misc'], $misc_num)) { $misc_num[$result['misc']] = 0;} $misc_num[$result['misc']] += 1;`. And you have to initialise `$misc_num` with an empty array (otherwise you'll get a warning).

Answer (score 0):

I am considering your following codes

```
$total = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders");
```

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($total))
{
 $cst[] = $result['customer'];
 $partnumber[] = $result['partnumber'];
 $misc[] = $result['misc'];
}

$misc = array(
              [0] => red, 
              [1] = >red, 
              [2] => blue, 
              [3] => blue, 
              [4] => blue,
              [5] => green,
              [6] =>red
              )
```

Now you can implement array_count_values() function here like

print_r(array_count_values($misc))

This results the following data

Array
  (
      [red] => 3
  [blue] => 3
  [green] => 1
)