# How to find the repeating elements in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have an array of n elements(numbers or words), I want to find all the elements which occur more than once in the array. What is the most efficient approach of doing this in terms of performance?

PS: I can sort the array first, but only if that doesn't affect the total performance much.
Also, though this is mainly php, i would like to know a algorithm or logic that can be implemented on other platforms too.

Comment: Is sorting the array first an option?

Comment: performance depends on the length of the array and also probably on the frequency of duplicates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Couting occurances of each value in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872835/couting-occurances-of-each-value-in-an-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
$new=array_filter(array_count_values($array),'custom_filter');
print_r($new);
function custom_filter($val)
{
  return $val > 1; 
}
```

output

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
)
```

Comment: You could add `array_filter`, like: `array_filter(array_count_values($array), function ($val) {
 return $val > 1;
});`

Comment: No need to create a function for that, you can just use `create_function()` to create a callable that gets automatically destroyed after use.. The only need to create a fully functional function is if you need to call that many times, from different parts of the code, etc.. (I miss Python lambda functions, in PHP..)

Answer (score 1):

There is a [array_count_values()](http://php.net/array_count_values) function provided by PHP itself.

It does more than what you need, but should be quite fast since it's compiled-in..

Then, of course, you need to filter out the result for keys which value is > 1.

**EDIT**

If you want a one-liner:

```
$a = array('a','b','c','a','a','b','d','e');
array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values($a), create_function('$x', 'return $x>1;')));
// array (0 => 'a', 1 => 'b');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$lookup = array();
foreach($array as $v) {
    if (!isset($lookup[$v]))
        $lookup[$v] = false;
    else if ($lookup[$v] == false) {
        echo "Duplicate $v\n";
        $lookup[$v] = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work

```
array_unique(array_diff($inputArray, array_unique($inputArray)));
```