# PHP - how many times

Tags: php, arrays, count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the repeating elements in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858306/how-to-find-the-repeating-elements-in-an-array)

If I have this array : array("hey", "test", "hey");

And I want to count how many times I have the word "hey", how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't it be great if there were a function like [array_count_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)?

</sarcasm>

---

Some example code of usage:

```
$arr = array(...);
$valCounts = array_count_values( $arr );
echo $valCounts['hey'];
```

I highly recommend browsing php.net and, in-particular, learning the [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;
foreach($array as $item) {
  if($item == 'hey') {
    $count++;
  }
}
print $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

The command is array_count_values. Check

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop over the array.

```
$x = 0;
foreach (array("hey","test","hey") as $value) {
    if ($value === "hey") $x++;
}
```

For a less efficient, but shorter, solution, you could use `array_count_value`.

```
$counts = array_count_values(array("hey","test","hey"));
$x = $counts["hey"];
```

Comment: I noticed you're using some [function array dereferencing](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html). Too bad php doesn't support it (in any released version).

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Haven't written any PHP code recently. I'll fix it.